# Convert Jira's time tracking field format to hours

Tags: ruby, jira

I am using JIRA api to extract timespent by users on issues. The time spent is in the format:

```
"12w 1d 2h 5m" or "12h" or "12m" etc
```

The API isn't exporting the number of hours. 
Is there a quick (requires no effort on my part) way to convert this to hours (or seconds). I suppose this is some sort of a standard format, is there a name for it?
I know how to do this myself, just don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: That's a strange response from an API, are you using the correct endpoint?

Comment: Yes I am. They also accept time in the same format on Jira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`chronic_duration`](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration) gem can parse that into seconds:

```
ChronicDuration.parse("12w 1d 2h 5m") # => 7351500
```

As far as I know that format isn't a standard. ISO 8601 does include [a format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), but that ain't it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JiraDurationUtils](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/util/JiraDurationUtils.html). It will use the Time Tracking configuration to convert properly.